# Add widget into list

Tags: flutter

I have some class like this

```
class View1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctx) {
    return Center(child: Text('Something'));
  }
}
class View2 extends StatelessWidget {
....
}
```

How can I add them into a list and assigned to the `children: <Widget>[]`.
For example, instead of

```
children: <Widget>[
                   view1() 
                   //or view2 
             ]
```

I want

```
children: <Widget>[
                   //for loop or something
                   list[i] 
                 ]
```

UPDATE:

The List a creat like this
`List list=['view1()','view(2)']`

and I got `The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget'.` when I try

```
children: <Widget>[
        Container(
         child: list,
          )]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
    children:list // list is widget list in your case
```

Comment: I got `The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget'.`

Comment: can you post your list also?

Comment: you are creating list as string, please remove ' ' from list type. i.e List list=[View1(),View2()]

Comment: Glad to help.  :)